# PyGObject: cairo context to pixbuf

Tags: cairo, pygobject, pycairo

```
    width, height = max(abs(fromo.realx - to.realx),3), max(abs(fromo.realy - to.realy),3)
    surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height)
    ctx = cairo.Context(surface)

    ctx.scale(width, height)
    ctx.move_to(0, 0)
    ctx.line_to(1, 1)
```

I have that, i want to convert the cairo context to a pixbuf so i can use it as Gtk.Image. Can I do that?

Comment: You should be able to use `set_from_surface()` to handle that using your ImageSurface as the surface. Let me know how it works, and I'll post as an answer.

Comment: Ok, i had to use the surface and not the context, thanks. I'm new using Cairo. And yes, gtk.Image.new_from_surface(surface) worked well, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`gtk_image_set_from_surface`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkImage.html#gtk-image-set-from-surface) for that:

```
gtk.Image.set_from_surface(surface)
```

or even make your image from the surface:

```
gtk.Image.new_from_surface(surface)
```